# Problema con el routing a archivos - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

Estoy empezando en el mundo de la programación web haciendo una pequeña aplicación para mi departamento.

El caso es que estoy utilizando una arquitectura MVC, haciendo routing a las diferentes direcciones de la web. Es decir, en un archivo tengo definidas las rutas a las que se puede acceder en la web, y si no están definidas te redirecciona a la página princiapl. Hasta aquí todo bien.

```
$router = new Router();

        //Registramos las url y sus funciones asociadas
           
                $router->get('/', [IndexController::class, 'index']);
                $router->get('/app', [appController::class, 'index']);
```

A continuación dejo la fórmula con la que se comprueban las rutas

```
public function comprobarRutas() {

            //Iniciamos la sesión y vemos si el usuario está logado
                if(!isset($_SESSION)){
                    session_start();
                }

                $auth = $_SESSION['login'] ?? false;

            //Revisa que las rutas estén definidas en el router, así como validar el tipo de request (GET o POST)
                $urlActual = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ?? '/';
                $metodo = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
                
                if($metodo === 'GET') {
                    $fn = $this->rutasGET[$urlActual] ?? null;

                }
                else {
                    $fn = $this->rutasPOST[$urlActual] ?? null;

                }

            //Si es una ruta protegida, verificamos si el usuario está logado
                if(in_Array($urlActual, $this->rutas_protegidas) && !$auth) {

                    //En el caso de que sea una ruta protegida y no estemos logados, nos envía a la página de login
                        header('Location: /login');

                }

            if($fn) {    
                //La url existe y hay una función asociad
                    call_user_func($fn, $this);
            }
            else
            {
                ob_start();     //Almacenamos los siguientes datos en memoria
                include_once __DIR__ . "/views/404.php";

                $contenido = ob_get_clean();    //Limpia el buffer

                include_once __DIR__ . "/views/layout.php";
                
            }
        }
```

Sin embargo, he encontrado un problema al intentar programar un gestor de archivos para esta aplicación. Quiero que esta aplicación permita subir archivos PDF (mediante un `<input type='file'>`, almacenar el archivo en el servidor y guardar la ruta en la que se almacena en MySQL para posteriormente abrirlo mediante una etiqueta como la siguiente:

```
<a href="/adj/Mi-archivo.pdf" target='_blank' rel='noopener'> Descargar</a>
```

Sin embargo, al dar click a este enlace para acceder a ese archivo, al no estar la ruta definida en el routing, me redirecciona a la página que tengo predeterminada en el caso de que la ruta no exista.

El código del routing es el siguiente:

¿Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar esto? Espero haberme explicado bien.

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Comment: porque no creas una ruta para los archivos donde el parametro sea el nombre?

Comment: A nivel de .htaccess debes aplicar reglas rewrite que identifiquen si el archivo existe, y si es así que lo sirva, sin pasar por tu index.php... estas mismo del wordpress te servirian: https://www.daggerhartlab.com/wordpress-rewrite-api-examples/